# NextJS: How do I get exportPathMap page data? I don't see it in getStaticProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have set up `exportPathMap` but I get an empty object when exporting `getStaticProps` from my component. I don't understand how I'm supposed to access it?

```
// next.config.js
exportPathMap: async function (
    defaultMapPath,
    { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
  ) {
    const paths = {}
    const response = await fetch(...)
    const data = await response.json()
    data.forEach((item) => {
      paths[`/item/${item.id}`] = {
        page: '/itemPage',
        query: {
          item,
        },
      }
    })

    return paths
  },
```

And

```
// itemPage.js
...
export async function getStaticProps(props) {
  console.log('props', props) // returns "props {}""

  return {
    props: props
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to find it specifically stated in the documentation right now, but here are your options.

**OPTION 1**

Use `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` like so (from "with-static-export" in the nextJS examples)

```
// [id].js post file

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const response = await fetch(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_page=1'
  )
  const postList = await response.json()
  return {
    paths: postList.map(post => {
      return {
        params: {
          id: `${post.id}`,
        },
      }
    }),
    fallback: false,
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  // fetch single post detail
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${params.id}`
  )
  const post = await response.json()
  return {
    props: post,
  }
}
```

**OPTION 2**

Use `exportPathMap` AND `getInitialProps`

```
// item.js
...
Page.getInitialProps = function (context) {
  return context.query.item
}
```

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...Same as in your question...
}
```

**Both will allow you to have static optimization.** With Option 1, you need not export, `next build` is sufficient. For Option 2 you will need to run `next export`

From: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

> If your pages don't have getInitialProps you may not need next export at all; next build is already enough thanks to Automatic Static Optimization.

Another note: You can use both methods inside a single project.